# c structure: Input requires number line by line by hitting "enter" after each number

Tags: c, scanf, conversion-specifier

How can I add the 10 digit number without write one digit in each line.

```
struct test {
  unsigned short telephone[10];
  //Some Code Here ... 
}

for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  scanf("%d", & seats[position - 1].telephone[j]);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: arvin , i edited your question , please tell me is that what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to mention,

- Honor the data type
- Make use of the *maximum field width* with scanf.

Write

```
 scanf("%1hu", &seats[position-1].telephone[j]);
     //  ^
```

which reads only 1 element from the input .

Note: the `h` is a *length modifiers* , which is described as

> `h`
>
> Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X` , or `n` conversion specifier applies
>   to an argument with `type pointer` to `short int` or `unsigned short
>   int`.

Also related, from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2/p9, (*emphasis mine*)

> **An
>   input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
>   any specified field width** and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence.